# Which of the following sets are subspaces of $\textbf{R}^{3}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, invariant-subspace

Which of the following sets are subspaces of $\textbf{R}^{3}$:

- A. $\{(x,x+7,x+3) \mid x\in\textbf{R}\}$
- B. $\{(x,y,z) \mid 7x + 3y + 2z = 0\}$
- C. $\{(x,y,z) \mid x,y,z > 0\}$
- D. $\{(x,y,z) \mid −6x − 5y − 4z = 9\}$
- E. $\{(x,0,0) \mid x\in\textbf{R}\}$
- F. $\{(−9x,6x,5x) \mid x\in\textbf{R}\}$

Can someone help me with this question?

I tried solving it with the definition of subspaces, but it didn't work.

I must have done something wrong.

Comment: @Don Thousand Not all of them. Some don't even contain the $0$ vector.

Comment: First of all check if the $0$ vector is in the subset. If not, then it can't be a subspace. If it is, check closure to addition and multiplication by a scalar. All straight from the definitions. Can you write where are you stuck?

Comment: I checked the 0 vector and got that c and d are definitely not subspaces then I checked and got that f is a subspace but with the others I'm stuck and I don't know how to solve them

Comment: it's not but it's okay take your time, I just want to know how to solve it and what's the correct answer because I couldn't solve it

Comment: @Michael I can understand your concern, but that seems like jumping to conclusions to me.

Comment: @Michael It is also very much plausible that this was an exercise problem from a textbook which the OP tried and failed to solve, for example. We just don't know, so assuming immediately that this is from an online exam and concluding thus that we need to delay answering does not seem to make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: @Michael what if I had an exam the next day and I really didn't know how to solve, I don't think that people are planing on cheating on their exams by asking questions here it's a really not a good idea.however, stop interfering with things that don't concern you

Comment: @Michael okay but some people actually need the help and have stuff to study before their exam and at first, I didn't mind the delay but seeing your response about that I was wanting more than the methodology and the way you responded to mark was really rude and some people can't wait 24 hours to get help for a question they could have the exam on the next day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's do $B$ as an example. The $0$ vector is there, ok. Now we have to check if it's closed to addition. Let's assume $(x_1,y_1,z_1),(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ are $2$ vectors in that set, i.e their coordinates satisfy $7x+3y+2z=0$. Now what about their sum? The sum of these vectors in $\mathbb{R^3}$ is $(x_1+x_2,y_1+y_2,z_1+z_2)$. And indeed:

$7(x_1+x_2)+3(y_1+y_2)+2(z_1+z_2)=(7x_1+3y_1+2z_1)+(7x_2+3y_2+2y_2)=0+0=0$

So the sum is there. This set is indeed closed to addition.

Now we have to check closure to multiplication by a scalar. Let $(x,y,z)$ be a vector in this set and let $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ be any scalar. Then $\lambda(x,y,z)=(\lambda x,\lambda y,\lambda z)$. And we have:

$7(\lambda x)+3(\lambda y)+2(\lambda z)=\lambda(7x+3y+2z)=\lambda\times 0=0$

So $\lambda(x,y,z)$ is in the set as well. So this is indeed a subspace, it is closed under all operations and contains the $0$ vector.

Comment: Thank you so much @Mark I'm sorry if I went to sleep and didn't answer I just saw your answer and it did help, I tried solving and got that b,e and f are subspaces is it correct? Thank you again

Comment: @Micheal, as I said before I didn't mind waiting and I still don't this question is an old practice question that's it and it took me so long because i just woke up and saw it

Comment: @Michael and I found it really rude of you assuming that just because I didn't answer fast you can't just go and accuse people of things you don't know

Comment: Yes, $B, E, F$ are subspaces. This is correct. Glad to see my answer was helpful. I really don't understand Michael's reaction.